# Adding a textblock to a custom wpf control (piepiece control from codeplex)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, pixelsense

I'm currently building a Surface application where the main navigation is a circular menu. For each menu item I'm using a custom control that I found on codeproject.com:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PieChartDataBinding.aspx (PiePiece control)

The number of submenu items (which is also piepiece controls) comes from a database and thus dynamically loaded. What I can't figure out is how I add a textblock to this custom control to display the submenu item text. It needs to follow the PiePiece's RotationAngle property to line up correctly.

Anyone got a hot-fix for this? I was thinking about adding another dependencyproperty to the piepiece custom control, but that way I can't set the font-family, size etc (can I?)

Any input on this is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you not using an items control or special panel for this?

Comment: Hey Jeff, no - i'm just using that PiePiece control and for every submenu item in the database, I'm adding a control to a canvas. Is there a better approach to this? I'm still learning xaml as you might have guessed already ;)

Comment: Still haven't found a solution to this.. anyone? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using an [Adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx), without taking a really close look the PiePiece Control you're using this might solve your problem.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry for the delayed response. Adorners seems like a perfect solution to my problem, however I'm a bit stuck when it comes to binding to the Text property from codebehind.

Basically I should be able to do something like this:
Binding binding = new Binding("Title");
myAdorner.Title = ??

Thanks again! :)

Comment: Not a problem, sorry I missed your comment on the 17th, but glad you figured it out.